# How to create wordpress child theme if folder name and theme name is different?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme with name Experon_Pro and in style.css the theme name is experon this is a paid theme and working fine.

For creating the child theme I created folder Experon_Pro-child and added below code in child theme style.css and copied the same functions.php to child theme from parent theme. But still it says parent theme is missing ?

child theme style.css contain below details.

```
/*
Theme Name: Experon Pro Child
Theme URI: http://www.thinkupthemes.com/themes/experon-pro/
Author: ThinkUpThemes
Author URI: http://www.ThinkUpThemes.com
Template: experon
Description: Experon is a multi-purpose professional Premium WordPress Theme ideal for a business or blog website. The theme is responsive, HD retina ready and comes with 600+ Google Fonts which can easily be selected directly from the theme options panel. Never code again with the awesome page builder. Simply drag, drop and you're done! It couldn't be easier to create stunning websites with the beauty of Harest.
Version: 1.6.0
License: GNU General Public License
License URI: /licenses/license.txt
Tags: black, dark, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, left-sidebar, fixed-layout, responsive-layout, fluid-layout, custom-header, custom-menu, full-width-template, theme-options, threaded-comments, editor-style, featured-images, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, grid-layout, footer-widgets, blog, e-commerce, education, entertainment, news, photography, portfolio
Text Domain: experon-child
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Template line should correspond to the `directory name` of the parent theme, so the Template will be `experon_pro`.